# My PHP function not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on something a bit more for myself, thats for another website that I own. It involves a lot of groups with permissions and such, and right now i have a function that looks like this

```
function hasPermission($user, $permission){
    global $connection;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE `ID` = '". $user ."'";

    $rs = $connection->query($sql);

    if ($rs){
        $user = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $userRank = $user['Rank'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ranks' WHERE `RankName` = '". $userRank ."'";
        $rs = $connection->query($sql);

        if ($rs){
            $rank = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);

            if ($rank[$permission] == 1){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo($connection->error);
    }
}
```

Then when I call the function with the parameters set like this `if (hasPermission($_SESSION['ID'], 'IsFullAccess') == true)` it returns false, and I get my custom error message saying I don't have permission. And yes, in my database, the "IsFullAccess" column is set to 1 for that rank.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `user id` stored as string ? are you sure `IsFullAccess` is stored in the DB ?

Comment: It is stored as an integer, however i have tried removing the quotes and i get the same result. And yes, I'm sure 'IsFullAccess' in the database

Comment: I noticed that I was assigning a variable $user to a new value, which since it was a parameter of the function, it could cause an issue. So I changed that, and I'm still getting the same issue. If anyone has any idea, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code, it seems like you're not familiar with sql's [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp):

your query looks something like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT r.$permission as p FROM admins a JOIN ranks r ON a.rank=r.RankName WHERE a.ID=$user";
$rs = $connection->query($sql);
if (!$rs)
    return false;
$hasPermission = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);
return $hasPermission['p'];
```

(keep in mind [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Make sure that the db returns the result you expect before testing it within php

Comment: I have no idea what you're assigning $sql to, very confused

Comment: Please read the links within the answer on SQL `JOIN`s, it would save you al lot of `php` code, and it's way more efficient

Comment: I've looked at MySQL join statements a bi more, and spent a few hours trying a few different solutions and I'm still unable to get it to work.

Comment: Could you post the solution you tried? A join would work and Uri's code looks good

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `hasPermission($_SESSION['ID'], 'IsFullAccess') == 1)` instead of `hasPermission($_SESSION['ID'], 'IsFullAccess') == true)`. (`true` should be convert to `1`)

Comment: Try using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would make a difference. If anything == would have a higher chance of working because === means you want to check if it's the same datatype. Even though they are I'm going to use == incase I forget to set the right type in the DB,